# Dropdown Menu over SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have an svg canvas full of interesting data visualizations using d3 and I'd like to have a traditional html dropdown menu appear above an svg:rect element. Is this possible? I realize I could use foreignObject, but that's incompatible with IE.

Comment: I think that's no problem.  I've got HTML tooltips on top of SVG.  You might need to adjust the CSS Z-index (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine as long as you arrange the elements correctly. In the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hkwD3/), I've used an absolute positioned DIV on top of the SVG element (move your mouse around the output window to see the DIV move around). (The code uses [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) rather than D3, but the results will be the same).

Comment: Thanks for the example. My problem did happen to be with the z-index, which I hadn't taken into account with a white SVG background.